# How to delete with QueryDSL when there is no Q-class?

Tags: querydsl

I have the following:

```
@Entity
public class Step {
...
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "InfoType")
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@CollectionTable(name = "Info", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "StepId"))
@Column(name = "Value", length = 100)
private Map<InfoType, String> infos = new HashMap<>();
...
}
```

The `InfoType` class is just an enum.

In the DB that translates to a table, `Step` and another table `Info`. The `Info` table has a foreign key to `Step`.

What I want to do is to delete `Step` records via a query. First I would need to delete from the `Info` table because of the FK, but there is no generated Q-class for `Info`. Is there a way to write such queries with QueryDSL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@ElementCollection` annotation operations are always cascaded. When you remove `Step` entity, the operation is cascaded to the `@ElementCollection`.

However, cascading operations is only effective when the operation is done via EntityManager. If you are trying to bulk delete the entities via custom query the operation will not be cascaded.

Possible solution would be to fetch all `Step` entities you want to delete and call the delete method for each of them.

Comment: So it is not possible the way I want. Thank you for the explanation!